# Failed Target Version 31 in Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins

I made target version 31 and I can't get build via jenkins.

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java JDK version was 1.8 on the Jenkins machine, and after I upgraded to JDK 11 and the problem was fixed.